# htmlentities on hidden form elements

Tags: html, forms, html-entities, sanitization

This might seem like a daft question but the sanitizing of user input continually confuses me, and i would like once and for all to get a definitive answer.

So heres the scenario

1. Customer fills in web form.
2. PHP checks that the mandatory fields have been filled in appropriately, if not it doesn't let the customer continue until they are.
3. If so then the user input is displayed on screen for confirmation, while the input data is also stored as hidden form elements.
4. Customer then confirms input, the hidden elements are then sent on for further processing.

Working with the principle that data shouldn't be escaped until the last minute, how would this apply to the data stored in the hidden elements at point 3. (Obviously the data printed on screen at this point i have applied htmlentities() too)

Should i use htmlentities on the hidden elements, however this is technically not the last stage as after part 4 i would then be using the variables again before sticking them into a DB or email.

I am fully aware that i might be doing this completely wrong, so any thoughts are very welcome. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing out the user's input to the page, it should ALWAYS be escaped. Otherwise there's nothing to stop people adding javascript etc to their input, or to try and escape out of your hidden fields and inject code onto the page. So yup, use htmlentities on the hidden fields too. Just because the user can't see them doesn't stop people from injecting code into them.

Comment: Thats what i thought but wont that cause me further issues down the line? Like having an name like O'Maley end up like O\'Maley before its entered into the DB?

Comment: If you're using htmlentities, that won't escape single quotes, just html stuff like " and < (thats the mySQL escape functions that do that). I'm not 100% as I don't use PHP that often, but do the htmlentities() escaped fields not come back as the unescaped text once you submit the form? If they don't you'll just need to remember to unescape them before you stick them in the DB.

Comment: Well im using prepared statements so that covers the single quotes etc, wasn't sure if htmlentities would attempt to do that also. Thanks i think i have enough to work with now. Cheers ^_^